# Is there a better way to replace the "for" loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Can someone help me?

I have a huge dataframe to work with (90 thousand rows) and I need to apply this logic, but I can only think of solving the problem using a 'for' loop, and this is taking almost 2 hours to run... Can someone give me some light on how I can optimize the code?

The logic is as follows:
For each 'Customer', I need to check if his 'FinalKey' exists in the 'Key' column. If it exists, the 'Final Name' of this customer will be the same as the most repeated name in 'Customer' for that same 'FinalKey' in 'Key'.
Here is an example below:

## Creates the dataframe df

```
data = [['Tom','123', '123'], ['Tom', '54', '123'], \
    ['Tom', '21', '123'], ['Tom2', '123', '123'], \
    ['Tom3', '123', '123'], ['Tom3', '123', '123'], \
    ['John', '45', '45'], ['Mary', '23', '41']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Customer', 'Key', 'FinalKey'])
df['Final Name']=''
```

## Print dataframe

df

| Customer | Key | FinalKey | Final Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 123 | 123 |  |
| Tom | 54 | 123 |  |
| Tom | 21 | 123 |  |
| Tom2 | 123 | 123 |  |
| Tom3 | 123 | 123 |  |
| Tom3 | 123 | 123 |  |
| John | 45 | 45 |  |
| Mary | 41 | 41 |  |

Here is the logic:

## Logic

```
for i in range(0, len(df['Customer'])):  

if str(df.loc[i, 'FinalKey']) in list(df['Key']):    
    df.loc[i, 'Final Name'] = df[df['Key']==df.loc[i, 'FinalKey']]['Customer'].value_counts().idxmax()

else:
    df.loc[i, 'Final Name'] = ""
```

df

```
| Customer |   Key   | FinalKey | Final Name | 
| -------- | ------- | -------- | ---------- |
|   Tom    |   123   |    123   |    Tom3    |
|   Tom    |    54   |    123   |    Tom3    |
|   Tom    |    21   |    123   |    Tom3    |
|   Tom2   |   123   |    123   |    Tom3    |
|   Tom3   |   123   |    123   |    Tom3    |
|   Tom3   |   123   |    123   |    Tom3    |
|   John   |    45   |     45   |    John    |
|   Mary   |    23   |     41   |            |
```

Comment: Pls explain in words what is the criteria for the Final Name

Comment: Not sure of me, but using list(df['Key']) in the for loop Can indicates that the list is reconstructed each Time. Calculate it outside and use the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way, but this works:

```
top_cust_by_key = df[['Key', 'Customer']].groupby('Key').agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])['Customer']
df['Final Name'] = df['FinalKey'].map(top_cust_by_key)
```

Comment: wow, it's perfect!!! I don't even know how to begin to thank you. thank you very much!!!